# How to select Development team for iOS app created in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to deploy an iOS app to Device using Google's Flutter, but I get this error on the command line:

```
Building an iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a Provisioning Profile
Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
  1- Opening the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- In the 'General' tab, make sure a 'Development Team' is selected
For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.io/setup/#deploy-to-ios-devices
Or run on an iOS simulator
```

Where and how do I do this? There is no "ios/Runner.xcworkspace" in the project. I know the installed Certificates and Provisioning profile work on my Mac, because I created and installed an app on my iOS device using Appcelerator, and it found everything I needed, and ran perfectly on device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select `Runner`, and navigate to `Signing & Capabilities`, under Signing, check `Automatically manage signing`, after that choose a `Team` from the list, and you're done.

[image]

Comment: "Runnner" Button does neither exist in Android Studio nor Xcode :(

Comment: One trick for flutter devs: you need to open the iOS folder in XCode. This is a subdirectory under the main project folder

Answer (score -1):

You have to sign in with your appleID at 'signing'. After that you can select your 'personal team'.

Answer (score -6):

`open ios/Runner.xcodeproj` and follow the same instructions should work?  `Runner.xcodeworkspace` is a relatively new addition to the template, created to allow Flutter projects to integrate better with CocoaPods.

If that doesn't work, please let us know.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your first sentence. "open ios/Runner.xcodeproj and follow the same instructions should work?" what does that mean?